# Regular expression to split optional groups

Tags: regex

Full string syntax is: "db:server:port"

Server and port are optional, i.e. can have partial strings, such as:

db

or

db:server

Trying to use:

```
(.*):?(.*)?:?(.*)?
```

- selects the whole string

Please advise.

Comment: The details are not quite clear. Is db required? If server and port are both optional, can you have port without server, and in that case, do you require both colons: `andromeda:1023` or `andromeda::1023`? Or, if you have port, is server required e.g. `andromeda:crichton:1023`?

Comment: I wrote: "Server and port are optional". By exclusion this means that db is not optional. I also described what partial combination are valid (db or db:server).

Answer (score 4):

Give this one a shot:

```
([^:]*?):?([^:]*?):?([^:]*?)$
```

Not sure what language you're using, so it may not work.

Example: http://regex101.com/r/eQ6bF0

Note on the example it's set for a global/multiline match - beware that this will match across newlines if you don't use the correct modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a language that I can see, so there may be different specific answers, but the basic problem is that .* will match a ":" character. That means the first term will suck the entire string in.  I would use ([^:]*) instead of (.*).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
([^:]+)(?::([^:]+)(?::([^:]+))?)?
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
(db|:server|:port)
```

will match any and all of these:

```
db:server:port
db
db:server
```

Working example:

http://regex101.com/r/rK1lI5

Comment: db, server and port words is just lexical it can be anything